# Crossfilter with multiple dimensions not working

Tags: javascript, crossfilter

I am using crossfilter. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/zwqn0ozo/5/) is the fiddle of the problem.

There are two dimensions I have create and two filters I want to apply on it.

```
var appliedFilters = {category: "LIFESTYLE", card: "GOLD"};
var cardDim, categoryDim;
```

This should return 700 according to the data, but it returns 1400.

please help.

Answer (score 0):

You are running cardDim.top(Infinity).forEach(function (d, i) { ... }) inside your loop over appliedFilters. Since there are 2 filters, it runs 2 times and adds 700 to totalMoneySpent each time.